# Compare login info to csv data and grant access

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My program asks the user whether they have an account or not. If the user doesn't have an account, then the program creates a new account for the user and stores their details in a csv file. This part works fine. But if the user runs the program again (after account creation) and tries to log in with the same details (username, password), it doesn't work. How do I compare the login info to csv data and grant access?

```
##Two Subjects----> Computer Science and History
import csv

def main():
    userAccount()

def userAccount():
    print('-------------------------------')
    userAccount = input('Do you already have an account: ')
    if userAccount == 'No' or userAccount== 'N' or userAccount == 'no' or userAccount == 'n':
        userSName = input('Name : ')
        userSAge = input('Age : ')
        userSYgroup = input('Year Group : ')
        userGname = userSName[:3] + userSAge
        print('Your username is : ',userGname.lower())
        userSword = input('Password: ')
        detail1 = [userSName,userSAge,userSYgroup,userGname,userSword]
        with open('userData.csv','w',newline = '') as csvfile:
            w = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter = ',')
            w.writerow(detail1)
    elif userAccount == 'Yes' or userAccount == 'Y' or userAccount == 'yes' or userAccount == 'y':
        userLName = input('Username: ')
        passLWord = input('Password: ')

        f = open('userData.csv','r',newline = '')
        for i in f:
            if userLName == f[0,3] and passLWord == f[0,4]:
                print('Log In Successfull')
            else:
                print('Incorrect Username or Password')
                main()      

main()
```

Comment: Hi @d_gauri. Welcome to SO. What exactly have you tried? Where are you stuck? What parts of the code are you having trouble understanding? The questions you ask are very broad and will most likely not be answered by anyone unless you provide some more details

Comment: When a user enters his details, I need the program to search the username and password from the file, then output whether the details are correct or not and whether the login details actually exist in the file or not.

Comment: @d_gauri That's still very broad. This "I need the program to ..." won't work. It should be "I need these lines to ...". You need to know what your program does and which parts need improvement. You can't expect anyone to read your 200+ lines and understand the logic. That's just having someone do your homework or w/e for you.

Comment: My program asks the user whether they have an account or not.  If the user doesn't have an account then, the program creates a new account for the user and stores their details in the file. This part works fine. But if the user runs the program again and tries to log in with the same details(username/password), it doesn't work.

Comment: The problem lies in these lines: -                                                                                               f = open('userData.csv','r',newline =" '')
        for i in f:
            if userLName == f[0,3] and passLWord == f[0,4]:
                print('Log In Successfull')
            else:
                print('Incorrect Username or Password')
                main()

Comment: @d_gauri Then rewrite your question. Remove irrelevant parts and isolate the problem which is comparing input (username, password) to csv data... You should read [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page if you plan to stay on SO for a while. If all your care is this single question and don't care about being part of SO, you'll probably get ignored.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I didn't realise that you didn't know the code inside out. Now, I have updated the question to the actual problem. I would like to be part of SO, so that I can learn new things and improve my programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully working version with slight changes. Add it to your original code. Though it might break your current code, because I changed a few variables name. Rename them accordingly.

```
##Two Subjects----> Computer Science and History
import csv

def main():
    userAccount()
    print("rest of the code")
    input() # keep window open

def userAccount():
    print('-------------------------------')
    # group possible inputs; no need for individual checks
    noAccount  = ["no", "NO", "n", "N"]
    yesAccount = ["yes", "YES", "y", "Y"]
    hasAccount = input('Do you already have an account: ')
    if hasAccount in noAccount:
        userName   = input('Name : ')
        userAge    = input('Age : ')
        userYear   = input('Year Group : ')
        userLogin  = (userName[:3] + userAge).lower()
        print('Your username is : ', userLogin)
        userPW     = input('Password: ')
        details    = [userName, userAge, userYear, userLogin, userPW]
        # open file with 'a' instead of 'w' so multiple records can be added to csv
        with open('userData.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(details)
        # once the account is created, return to beginning
        main()
    elif hasAccount in yesAccount:
        userLogin = input('Username: ')
        userPW    = input('Password: ')
        granted   = None
        with open('userData.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            # loop every row (record) in the csv file
            for row in reader:
                csvLogin = row[3]
                csvPW    = row[4]
                if userLogin == csvLogin and userPW == csvPW:
                    granted = True
                    print('Log In Successfull')
                    # a user is matched; no need to check other records
                    break
        # if input doesn't match any csv record, return to beginning
        if granted is None:
            print('Incorrect Username or Password')
            main()
    else:
        # if user enters something other than yes/no, return to beginning
        main()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much